# java.lang.ClassFormatError while loading class

Tags: classloader, abstract-factory, classformaterror

I am implementing the AbstractFactory pattern allowing outsiders to create Factories. I am reading the factory implementation name from a properties file, loading the factory class and using it to construct objects. Problem is that somewhere in my factory implementation when I'm trying to create an object of a task I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Code
>   segment has wrong length in class file
>   com/testsuite/loadperformancetesterusage/tasks/GetUrl

Following is the GetUrl constructor, nothing fancy!

```
public GetUrl( String protocol, String port, String hostname, String path, String producerClassName ) {
    super(producerClassName);
    this.protocol = protocol;
    this.hostname = hostname;
    this.port = port;
    this.path = path;
}
```

Any feedback on what might be happening here? Cross posted [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/594047/java/java/java-lang-ClassFormatError-while-loading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some mismatch in the version of classes i was using. It works now.

Comment: what do you mean by mismatch ?

Comment: This was awhile back but as far as i remember, i had compiled the class using some java version and was trying to load it using another version.