# hibernate project Code segment has wrong length in class file com/mysql/jdbc/PreparedStatement

Tags: java, hibernate

I am running a Hibernate Project....and getting an error

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Code segment has wrong length in class file com/mysql/jdbc/PreparedStatement
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:110)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:76)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2006)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1289)
at com.org.main.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:21)
```

My student class

```
package com.org.rani;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Student {

@Id
private int studId;
@Column
private String studName;
@Column
private String studAddress;

public int getStudId() {
    return studId;
}

public void setStudId(int studId) {
    this.studId = studId;
}

public String getStudName() {
    return studName;
}

public void setStudName(String studName) {
    this.studName = studName;
}

public String getStudAddress() {
    return studAddress;
}

public void setStudAddress(String studAddress) {
    this.studAddress = studAddress;
}

}
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" >
<hibernate-configuration>

<!-- a SessionFactory instance listed as /jndi/name -->
<session-factory>
    <!-- properties-->

<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
/School</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <mapping class="com.org.rani.Student"/>

</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

My HibernateTest class

```
package com.org.main;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

import com.org.rani.Student;

public class HibernateTest {

/**
 * @param args
 */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student st = new Student();
        st.setStudId(1);
        st.setStudName("Rinki");
        st.setStudAddress("Bangalore");           
        SessionFactory sf = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=sf.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(st);
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: related link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667377/java-lang-classformaterror-while-loading-class

Comment: I replaced mysql-connector.jar "mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin" with "mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin" now I am able to do transaction..

Comment: Good. Please post your comment as an answer and select it.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced mysql-connector.jar "mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin" with "mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin" now I am able to do transaction..